# Meteor-react ES6 Class React.Component

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I'm not sure if this is a known issue in Meteor. They did say that they are not supporting Modules in 1.2,but I don't know if this is a module issue or something else.

I'm attempting to structure my React components using ES6 classes, like so:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <p>Hello World</p>
    }
};
```

And then I add this route:

```
const {Router, Route} = ReactRouter;

Meteor.startup(function() {
    React.render((
        <Router>
            <Route path="/" component={App} />
        </Router>
    ), document.body)
});
```

This runs properly if it's all the same .jsx file.  Unfortunately, it doesn't work if I split the App and Router into separate files.  I get this from the browser:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined
```

Any ideas?  It works fine in two separate files if I go back to the createClass() syntax.  I tried adding an "export class", that didn't work, it returns an "Unexpected reserved word" error.

Obviously this isn't a huge problem, I can certainly use the createClass syntax, but I'm building a new app and thought I'd give it a try with the latest and greatest.

Thanks!
--Ivan

Comment: Are you importing App?

Answer (score 3):

Change your first line to:

```
App = class App extends React.Component {
```

That puts 'App' into the global namespace.

Comment: Perhaps this is not what you intended, but using globals in JavaScript is Douglas Crockford's No. 1 "[Awful Part](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/awful-parts.html)"

Answer (score 1):

Check this [demo](https://github.com/vazco/demo_modules) and add `universe:modules` to your modules. Try to use this in your `app.jsx`:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <p>Hello World</p>
    }
}
```

And in your parent:

```
import App from "./app"
```